# Haskell and laziness: Store often used values as members or just calculate on the fly?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, regarding its lazy nature, is it better to store frequently calculated values as data members, or is it safe, in standard, non-extended Haskell, to not do so.

To get a better grasp of what I mean, an example:

```
data Image = Image { size :: Int, inverse_size :: RealFrac }

new_image size = Image { size = size, inverse_size = 1.0 / fromIntegral size }
```

or shall I just declare it where it is used, assuming that `function` is called very often:

```
data Image = Image { size :: Int } -- no tainting

something (Image size) =
    let inverse_size = 1.0 / fromIntegral size -- possibly make a function of it
    in ...
```

Being a lazy language, and coming from C++ template metaprogramming, I am not sure how much Haskell will memoize such computations anyways.

Does this make any difference, runtime-speed- and storage-wise?

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward case of trading off memory use for computation speed. It will make precisely the obvious difference and which is better depends on the program, and is thus a question best answered with a profiler.

Comment: It certainly doesn't make any difference whatsoever for something like merely the _size_ of an image. It might matter for e.g. `Image { pixels, fourierTransformed :: Array (Int,Int) Float }`, but as said by C.A.McCann it's only the obvious difference, which means it depends on the application which alternative is better.

Comment: I also ask this because I would think Haskell memoizes some of its computations.

Comment: @phresnel: It is very often the case that indiscriminate run-time memoization burns lots of memory for little to no benefit. It's not something you want the compiler doing behind your back.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: So it seems my intuition was wrong in that it somehow coupled the concepts of lazyness and memoization. It seems learning Haskell when coming from imperative languages is great stuff to train and detangle your brain.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Though it was just an example. In my real case, it is spectral power distributions and a clean design therof where this question came up.

Comment: @phresnel: It's actually an incredibly common misconception among people learning Haskell. It is true that purity and laziness make simple memoization trivial--just define a full lookup table for the function and let laziness fill in the values when you need them. But that doesn't mean memoizing arbitrary functions is something the compiler will or should do automagically.

Comment: @phresnel: Note that in your second example, `inverse_size` will be computed at most once and the result shared among any uses of it within the body of the `let` expression, whereas if you inlined it, or applied a top-level function like `inverseSizeOf img` everywhere instead, the result would be recomputed each time. The kind of shared computation you have for `inverse_size` within the `let` expression is what gets mistaken for memoization.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Add to that that I was chilled by the memory consumption of a simple toy ray caster I wrote, taking magnitudes more memory than a C++ equivalent. I guess I just didn't write it well, and didn't use compiler options properly.

Comment: @phresnel: A number-crunchy program using ghastly amounts of memory sounds like a case of not being used to thinking in terms of how lazy evaluation and garbage collection interact, and ending up with too many thunks referencing intermediate results for no reason.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: I was thinking about that already: Indeed I held the data completely until I dumped the result. Instead, I should do like with the expression-templates-idiom-applied-to-numerical-processing in C++, and compute the data only at the moment it is needed; otherwise there is that "collection barrier" between crunching and printing. Lots of enlightenments today. Quick note to myself: Get familiar with Haskell's GC

Comment: @phresnel: Getting familiar with [GHC's profiling support](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html) would be helpful too. :]

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Funny link, because I was already looking forward to buy a copy of "Real World Haskell". "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" is a sweet introduction, but I really have to go the outside world now :)

Answer (score 2):

Denormalization - performance trade-off is not a Haskell-specific thing. If the `Image` type you have given as an example is close to reality, and you operate with large amount of `Image`s, you would hardly improve performance by means of precalculating `inverse_size`, because you are saving 1 operation of putting value on FPU stack and 1 floating-point division at the cost of 1 extra load from memory (if `size` is used in `something` function along with `inverse_size`), and x2-3 memory usage increase. It is not a great achievement.

Any way, to give a chance to `inverse_size` you should make sure this field is strict:

```
data Image = Image { size :: !Int, inverse_size :: !Float }
```

Otherwise such precalculation would be certainly pointless.

If you are wondering if GHC compiler optimizes such things itself, the answer is: GHC is able to float repetitive computation within one function (or several (nested by calling) functions if they are inlined), but of cause it won't make a new field in your data structure itself.

Comment: Even so, GHC is (and should be) cautious about doing things that could cause space leaks. Sometimes recomputing is actually faster because it means you're not hoarding piles of pre-computed junk in memory all the time and can use that memory for something else instead. Floating out common sub-expressions and sharing a single computed result can be a pessimization in some cases.

Comment: "you should make sure this field is strict" that again depends on the application. If it's something that's expensive to calculate (only then does memoising make any sense at all!) but sometimes not even used in any way, it's obviously better to leave the field lazy.

Comment: Note my question also targets clean designs (but I only mentioned it inside a comment saying "tainting"). Not having that precalculation within the Image-type (which really was just an example) appears to me as a cleaner interface. In other languages, like C++, I would make such value private. I think my real problem was that my intuition, coming from C++ templates, somehow coupled the concepts of memoization and lazyness.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I wrote this for `Image` type specially. Lazy 8 byte link field for 4 byte float, which is used "very often"? I don't think so.